# Why is my keyboard messed up in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to type in a pair of angle brackets in Eclipse, like "<>". However it shows up as a single quotation and a dot, like "'.". I tried a couple of times and found out that the angle bracket is actually located at back-slash's position.

Why is this happening? How can I change it back?

Thanks in advance.

Xi

Comment: Maybe you switched to non-english keyboard layout or something?

Comment: @serg555: He might have a "non-english" keyboard layout.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I think this has to do with an annoying feature of Windows - I've had something similar for a long time in different programs (not just Eclipse).

If you have a non-English version of Windows, you probably have different keyboard layouts installed (for example, I have a Dutch and a US English layout installed by default). The key combination <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> switches between keyboard layouts. It's very annoying and it's a really strange feature - as if the keys on someone's keyboard would suddenly change?!

You can go into Control Panel, Keyboard Settings and remove the layouts that you don't want to use. (I removed the Dutch layout so there's only US English left), so that you can't switch to the wrong layout by accident again. Or you can go to the Advanced Key Settings in Keyboard Setting and turn off the key combination.

Comment: To get back to your keyboard layout just press "Alt + Shift" in eclipse, no need to remove the keyboard layouts feature on windows.

Comment: @oneeyejack Yes, that works, but by removing the unnecessary keyboard layouts, you won't accidentally switch to a wrong one anymore.

Comment: I think you can disable the Alt-Shift shortcut in windows preferences, then you can't accidentally trigger it anymore.

Comment: @Jesper simply press alt+shift in eclipse again.. changes it back.. your answer is great on how to prevent. But this puts it back..

Comment: The most annoying thing about this is, that the use of (left) Alt-Shift coinsides with the Eclipse keyboard shortcut for renaming an entity, Alt-Shift-R. Just miss the R, and you're screwed.

Comment: First time I hear that this particular windows feature is strange. Can be annoying? sure... but strange? Some keyboards has different keys associated with the same buttons, take Russian keyboard for example. So this feature allows you to quickly jump between different layouts.
http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Genius_russian_keyboard.jpg

Comment: Is there a way to disable the alt+shift switching between keyboard layouts?

Answer (score 68):

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>. If you don't want to spend time removing keyboard layouts like Jesper suggested, just hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> until you get the layout you need. It usually doesn't take more than a couple times. :)

Comment: Saved my life today on Windows 7

Answer (score 9):

In windows 7 the language bar uses the <kbd>LEFT ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key sequence to change languages, so you can quickly change the language say to Spanish when writing a mail.

This sequence conflicts with many Eclipse shortcuts that use <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, like rename!

You can remove the OS's setting by control panel > keyboards and languages > change keyboards > advanced key settings.

Julio

Answer (score 9):

I Am Doing This Via Windows Control Panel.

First time when changing font.I am restart Eclipse.(No solution than that to save my time) and then do this.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

... Maybe you have your keyboard set for a different Locale(country)?

Also, you would probably be better asking this on SuperUser

Comment: Thanks. It helps. I have already solved the problem.

I am asking it here because it only happens in my Java Eclipse --- not even in PHP Eclipse! Weird, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Actually i think this must be something with Java SDK, because im having the same problem with IntelliJ. For example, in

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ImageView iv
    }
}
```

when i try to complete this snippet, with

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_imagem);
```

after "iv" the character set in my keyboard is screwed, and instead of a QWERTY keyboard (i have portuguese language defined, and dont have other keyboards in control pannel) i have a AZERTY

in windows, other applications are is still normal

Comment: why was this question downvoted? it seems valid, in the proper thread, and the issue is still unresolved!

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard handling of Eclipse is not perfect indeed: it confuses ctrl-alt with "altgr"!

So for example with Hungarian keyboard layout you cannot enter character '&', as it requires pressing <kbd>altgr</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> - but <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> was set to "SVN commit" by default...
(of course no problem in un-binding that combination in Eclipe, but it was not straightforward that ctr-alt conflicts with altgr, so what to look for)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was editing Java code in Eclipse and the keyboard layout suddenly changed. On my windows taskbar I have a keyboard icon and I used it to change the keyboard layout between United States-International and Dutch. That did not solve my problem. My problem was solved when I had restarted Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this probably happens if your script in Eclipse uses Robot class or any statements that use the combination of the keys, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> OR <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>. These combinations mess up with the functions of other keys after your script execution is completed or if it is stopped in between.

If you want to confirm if any of these combination is really messing up with your keys, then in your *testng.xml* file, just mouseover on any class name and it will be highlighted and underlined automatically, even though we have not pressed <kbd>ALT</kbd> nor <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> at this moment.  It means that these keys are not released yet even though your script might have released them.

If you face this problem, then the control being in Eclipse, press **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>** and press **<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>**, and this resolves the above problem. Now, the keys in your keyboard work as usual.

Answer (score -1):

with me, the strange thing is outside of eclipse (i use the ADT package), everything is ok. And restarting workspace, fixes the problem

this happens when i type any expression that might not be valid, like when i try to write

taskNameEditText = (EditText)findVie

of course, i want to write

taskNameEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.task_name);

but after the first snippet, it changes the keyboard. And the code completion stops working too. So far the only working solutions i found where: 1 - restarting eclipse, 2 - start using IntelliJ

changing the key bindings wont work, just because i already have those unset. Also, "Alt + Shift" wont work, because this is not a windows (i use 7, 64 bits) problem