# Eclipse - Output character different from Keyboard Key Value

Tags: java, eclipse

I am having a strange problem with Eclipse. The problem is that

- For some keyboard keys, the output value printed on screen is different from actual value of that key. e.g. When I press `#` key, it prints `£` sign instead.  Similarly when i try quotes key `"` , the `@` is printed instead.
- Outside the eclipse, the keys work fine.

Comment: I think this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806173/why-is-my-keyboard-messed-up-in-eclipse) could help you.

Comment: This is the same problem i guess

[Same Problem ][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806173/why-is-my-keyboard-messed-up-in-eclipse

Comment: @shamis thanks a lot. Sweet solution to a nagging problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think u should change your keyboard settings. It may be in any other english version type.