# Keyboard Layout Issue in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard

Okay, so I'll start off by saying I have seen the keyboard layout answer here:[Why is my keyboard messed up in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806173/why-is-my-keyboard-messed-up-in-eclipse) and this hasn't helped me at all.

My issue actually only concerns the numbers 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 0 on the keyboard. Whenever I type any of these numbers they appear as A, Z, Y, J, a white space, and 9, respectively.  Even in the line numbers they display this way as you can see in the image below.

[image]

I just used Eclipse a week ago and everything was fine and then I opened it back up to the code I left off at and everywhere these numbers existed they were changed, yet the code still compiles as though the number values are still there.  Oddly enough, I then downloaded netbeans and the same issue appears there as well

Comment: Looks like the *font* they are using is broken. This would be a Java or OS issue, not Eclipse or NetBeans. Try changing the font: `Preferences` > `General` > `Appearance` > `Colors and Fonts` > `Basic` > `Text Font`. Make sure you select a fixed-width font.

Comment: I love you forever <3 I changed some font settings for CS:GO to change the bomb code and that was it!! Thank you so much, weird how it only affects my IDE's. Nevertheless, you are my savior good sir